# Make dictionary from two lists using Counter object

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter, idioms

I have the following list:

```
name = ["Anne", "Jack", "Mary"]
```

I also have a nested list where each element is another list and is connected with the name present in the index of `name` list. This is shown below:

```
n1 = [[0, 0, 3], [0, 5, 5], [1, 3, 3]]
```

So for `'Anne'`, the first element in list `name`,  the list from `n1` connected to it is the first element `[0, 0, 3]`.

Similarly, for `"Jack"`, the second element in list `name`, the list from `n1` connected to it is the second element `[0, 5, 5]`, and so forth.

I want to count the occurrence of each number in each element of  `n1` and connect it to the names in `name` list in a dictionary format.

So I want my output to look like the below:

```
{'Anne': {'0': 2, '3': 1}, 'Jack': {'0': 1, '5': 2}, 'Mary': {'1': 1, '3': 2}}
```

I have tried the below:

```
      from collections import Counter
      clust = {}
      for val in name:
         clust[val] = {}
         for e in n1:
             wc = Counter(str(e1) for e1 in e)
             clust[val] = dict(wc)
```

But this gives me the output:

```
clust = {'Anne': {'1': 1, '3': 2}, 'Jack': {'1': 1, '3': 2}, 'Mary': {'1': 1, '3': 2}}
```

Which is incorrect. How do I achieve the output that I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to match the data from `n1` with each item in `name`; the easiest way is with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> name = ["Anne", "Jack", "Mary"]
>>> n1 = [[0,0,3], [0,5,5], [1,3,3]]
>>> {name_: Counter(data) for name_, data in zip(name, n1)}
{'Anne': Counter({0: 2, 3: 1}), 'Jack': Counter({5: 2, 0: 1}), 'Mary': Counter({3: 2, 1: 1})}
```

*(Note the use of a "dictionary comprehension", see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).)*

If the keys in your `Counter`s being strings is crucial, you can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to convert the integers before counting:

```
>>> {name_: Counter(map(str, data)) for name_, data in zip(name, n1)}
{'Anne': Counter({'0': 2, '3': 1}), 'Jack': Counter({'5': 2, '0': 1}), 'Mary': Counter({'3': 2, '1': 1})}
```

Comment: OP had string keys in the counter (not sure why though, +1 anyway)

Comment: Is there anyway to remove the keyword "Counter" from the output?

Comment: @user1452759 why do you want to? You can treat a `Counter` just like a vanilla `dict`, and it gives you extra functionality (e.g. `most_common` method, easy updates with more items, sensible arithmetic).

Comment: The reason I asked for that was because I wasn't sure if I could insert the "clust" dict/json to MongoDB with the "Counter" keyword. But it is possible. So that's not an issue. And also the reason I want the keys as "str" is because it won't insert in MongoDB otherwise

Comment: @user1452759 ah, I see. For the most part, `Counter` is compatible wherever a `dict` is; `isinstance(Counter(), dict)` is `True` because it's a subclass (this is why `isinstance` is preferred to checking `type`, too).

Answer (score 2):

For each name, your `for e in n1:` loop loops over all the elements of n1, making a Counter for each of them, and setting `clust[val]` to the result. So `clust[val]` ends up as the result of only the last item in `n1`.

You should use `zip()` to combine the two lists name and n1 into one, or probably better, the names list and the resulting Counters from n1. `zip()` returns tuples with the elements taken from both lists (`zip([1, 2], ['a', 'b']) becomes [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]`. You can make a `dict` from such tuples directly.

So:

```
clust = dict(zip(name, [Counter(e) for e in n1]))
```

Comment: Is there any way to remove the keyword "Counter" from this output?

Comment: Turn `Counter(e)` into `dict(Counter(e))`, I guess. You lose some handy functionality, but you might not need it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use index value of the `name` list to count items in the `n1` sublist. This can be done using `enumerate(name)`. It returns value and its index. Use this returned index to count items in `n1` sublist corresponding to item in `name`.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> name = ["Anne", "Jack", "Mary"]
>>> n1 = [[0,0,3], [0,5,5], [1,3,3]]
>>> clust = {}
>>> for i,val in enumerate(name):
...     wc = Counter(str(e1) for e1 in n1[i])
...     clust[val] = dict(wc)
... 
>>> clust
{'Anne': {'0': 2, '3': 1}, 'Jack': {'0': 1, '5': 2}, 'Mary': {'1': 1, '3': 2}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get this like this

```
from collections import Counter
name = ["Anne", "Jack", "Mary"]
n1 = [[0,0,3], [0,5,5], [1,3,3]]
clust = {name[i]: Counter(n1[i]) for i in range(len(name))}
```

Output is:

`{'Anne': Counter({0: 2, 3: 1}),
 'Jack': Counter({5: 2, 0: 1}),
 'Mary': Counter({3: 2, 1: 1})}`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an one liner to get the output that you want:

```
zip(name, [dict(Counter(z)) for z in [[str(y) for y in x] for x in n1]])
```

To break it down:

- `[[str(y) for y in x] for x in n1]` converts the n1 elements to list
- `dict(Counter(z))` create a list with counts the elements for each n1 list
- `zip` combines the two lists